# Does hammer.js handle touchmove?

Tags: javascript, mobile, web, touch, hammer.js

Is that hammer.js only handle touchstart/touchend, and it doesn't handle touchmove?

For my app, I need to know the path of the touch, the more details, the better.

Thanks

Patrick

Answer (score 3):

To obtain the touch move data, you need to use either pan or swipe. Here's sample code for pan:

```
var hammer = new Hammer(div);

// this sets pan to behave similar to normal touch/mouse input
// note that by setting the threshold to 0, pan will receive all inputs
hammer.get('pan').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL, threshold: 0 }); 

hammer.on('panstart', touchstart);
hammer.on('panmove', touchmove);
hammer.on('panend', touchend);
```